# Spinner does not show items [android, mysql, php, json]

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to make an app that takes the list of values from MySQL database
the spinner should display just names then I will get an id of this name to move it to other activity
the problem is that the spinner does not display anything at runtime
even though it's working well when I run just PHP page
please I need help
this is my code

```
public class ChooseScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    String emailToPass;
    String organizer_ID;
    private Spinner eventSpinner;
    private ArrayList <Event> eventsList;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String URL_Event = "http://192.168.1.3/Tactic1/list.php?organizer_ID="+organizer_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_scan);
        emailToPass = getIntent().getExtras().getString("emailToPass");
        eventSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerEventID);
        eventsList = new ArrayList<Event>();
        eventSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void populateSpinner() {
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < eventsList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(eventsList.get(i).getName());
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);


        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        eventSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);



    }

    private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChooseScanActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("get events..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_Event, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray frutas = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("frutas");

                        for (int i = 0; i < frutas.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) frutas.get(i);
                            Event event = new Event(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                    catObj.getString("nombre"));
                            eventsList.add(event);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "¿No ha recibido ningún dato desde el servidor!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
        }

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Seleccionado" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

        protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getSqlDetails();
    }


    private void getSqlDetails(){

        String url= "http://192.168.1.3/Tactic1/getOrganizerID.php?emailOrg="+emailToPass;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            organizer_ID = jObj.getString("organizer_ID");

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), organizer_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if(error != null){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

        );

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }



}
```

here the code of service handler

```
public class ServiceHandler {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

here the code of event class

```
public class Event {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Event(){}

    public Event(int id, String name){
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

code of XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChooseScanActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="@string/select_event"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerEventID"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code of PHP

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$answer = array() ;  
$answer [ "event" ] = array ( ) ;  
$organizer_ID =$_GET['organizer_ID'];

$sql = "select name_Event, event_ID from event where organizer_ID = '$organizer_ID'";

$result = mysqli_query ( $conn , $sql ) ;
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result )){  
$tmp = array () ;  
$tmp ["event_ID"] = $row["event_ID"] ;  
$tmp ["name_Event"] = $row["name_Event"] ;  
array_push ( $answer ["event"] , $tmp ) ;
}
// Keep the response header to json
header ( 'Content-Type: application / json' ) ;
// Listening to json's result
echo json_encode ( $answer ) ; 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new member  in stack overflow, how can I put other block of code in separated way ?

Comment: You could go one line below and write a description for your new block of code then select curly braces to add new block of code.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen that your `populateSpinner()` method is called only in `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method and `AsyncTask` never get called. Therefore you could not get any data.

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_scan);
        emailToPass = getIntent().getExtras().getString("emailToPass");
        eventSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerEventID);
        eventsList = new ArrayList<Event>();
        eventSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //start the task
        new GetEvents().execute();
    }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: where should I write this ? I wrote in onCreate but doesn't work

Comment: is it showing an error? your PHP, is it in local or remote? I'd like to see the outputted JSON